# Thymeleaf not recognizing attribute from service

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm working on two e-mail templates, one that will send a confirmation URL to verify the user's account and another one that will send a reset password link.

Activate account

```
<p>Use <a th:href="${confirmationUrl}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">this link</a> to activate your account now</p>
```

Reset password

```
<a th:href="${resetPasswordUrl}" target="_blank">Reset password</a>
```

Both links receive a `th:href` attribute that comes from the following methods :

This method sends the verification token link to activate the account

```
public void sendVerificationToken(User user) {
    String token = jwtTokenService.genEmailVerificationToken(user.getId());
    logger.info("Sending verification token to user. user={} email={} token={}",
            user.getId(), user.getEmail(), token);
    String confirmationUrl = null;
    try {
        confirmationUrl = new URIBuilder(verifyEmailUrl)
                .addParameter(VERIFY_EMAIL_ENDPOINT_PARAM, token)
                .build().toString();
        model.addAttribute("confirmationUrl", confirmationUrl);
    }

    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        logger.error("URL stored as redirect url for verify email is not valid.");
        throw ErrorFactory.serverError("Error");
    }
    emailService.sendAccountConfirmationEmail(user.getEmail(), confirmationUrl);
}
```

This method sends the password reset link

```
public void resetPasswordRequest(User user) {
    logger.info("Request for password recovery. email={}",
            user.getEmail());
    String token = jwtTokenService.genPasswordResetToken(user.getId());
    String resetPasswordUrl = null;
    try {
        resetPasswordUrl = new URIBuilder(resetPasswordUrl)
                .addParameter(RESET_PASS_ENDPOINT_PARAM, token)
                .build().toString();
        model.addAttribute("resetPasswordUrl", resetPasswordUrl);
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        logger.error("URL stored as target url for reset password email is not valid.");
        throw ErrorFactory.serverError("Error");
    }
    emailService.sendPasswordReset(user.getEmail(), resetPasswordUrl);
}
```

The way I'm trying to get the `confirmationUrl` and `resetPasswordUrl` to use in the HTML template is by declaring a Model param as a class level attribute above these two methods, and then using `model.addAttribute("attributeName", attribute)`.

```
private Model model;
```

But for some reason, I'm getting `Cannot resolve 'resetPasswordUrl'` and `Cannot resolve 'confirmationUrl'` on the template files. Like it's not recognizing the attributes.

Comment: is your `sendVerificationToken` method in a Controller class ? why not hand the Model as a method param ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you injecting your model object to the html template ?
Because I can't see that in your question.

Use `SpringTemplateEngine` and inject your template variables in this way :

```
Map<String, Object> variable = objectMapper.convertValue(yourModelObject, Map.class);
Context context = new Context(); //org.thymeleaf.context.Context class
context.setVariables(variable);
html = springTemplateEngine.process("your_template_name", context);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what @Srinivasa Raghavan said. I don't think it is necessary to use the model object in the mailing steps.

**1** - It will be sufficient if your method that sends your confirmation url works like this. **You can adjust the sample code for more general use.**

```
public void sendAccountConfirmationEmail(String recipient, String confirmationUrl) {

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("confirmationUrl", confirmationUrl);

        MimeMessagePreparator mimeMessagePreparator = mimeMessage -> {
            MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, "UTF-8");
            messageHelper.setFrom("Test <test@test.com>");
            messageHelper.setTo(recipient);
            messageHelper.setSubject("Active Account");
            String content = templateEngine.process("your_active_account.html", context);            
            messageHelper.setText(content, true);
        };

        mailSender.send(mimeMessagePreparator);
    }
```

**2** - In order to process our templates, you will configure a TemplateEngine especially configured for email processing, in our Spring Email configuration. You can reference [thymeleaf documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmail.html#spring-configuration) to create `TemplateEngine`.